# Error message attempting to install ubuntu-MATE 17.04 to pc w/ Intel H110 chipset

Tags: system-installation, mate

Here is the error msg displayed before installation begins:

```
[ 0.018063] ACPI Error: [\SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure. AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dwsload-210)
[ 0.018063] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog  
20160930/psobject_227)    
[ 0.018097] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rup08) while loading table (20160930/tbxfload-228)
[ 0.024062] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 4 successful (20160930/tbxfload-246)
```

The resulting distro installation does not display menuing system and doesn't respond to mouse or keyboard except when pressing on/off button on case.

EDIT: Got the same results with Ubuntu Gnome 17.04
I don't know how to send a bug report but I think there is one.
I think I'll try Ubuntu MATE 16.10.

EDIT2: Ubuntu Mate installed. I'm typing this from U.M.16.10 now. Finally.
There is something about ubuntu 17.04 that triggers this error and failed installation.

EDIT3: Ubuntu Mate 16.10 is working fine, or should I say *was* working fine.
I decided to let it update and so it did. It was time to restart and so I did.
It is back to a failed install and now I can't see how I can ever update Ubuntu without rendering it useless. So...until the people at Canonical fix this I will need to go elsewhere for my Linux fix.